# Why is my background image disappearing when scrolling?

Tags: android, xml, background

In my android app i have got an activity that uses a linear layout to display various rows of text views. The problem is that when scrolling up and down in the activity the background image disappears. In the emulator when I hold down the mouse button to begin scrolling the bg image disappears. When letting go the mouse button, the bg image comes back.

I am using this in my xml file to set the bg image:

```
android:background="@drawable/wallpaper"
```

What can I do to solve this strange behavior?

Comment: I've seen such behaviours with emulator? Did you try the same on a real device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the background on the scroll view, not on the linear layout.